# @Resource returns null when getBean does not

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

I have a piece of code that uses Spring dependency injection with ApplicationContext

```
public abstract class BigDataParent {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BigDataOperation.class);

    protected static ApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file.xml");

    ...
}
```

And the child:

```
public class BigBadChild extends BigDataParent  {

    private Something query;

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        query = (Something) context.getBean("beanName");

        ....
    }
}
```

I want to change the injection to use annotations instead of context, so I have just changed the child class to

```
public class BigBadChild extends BigDataParent  {

    @Resource(name = "beanName")
    private Something query;

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // Removed query = (Something) context.getBean("beanName");

        ....
    }
}
```

I have also changed my xml configuration file and have added

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
```

But now I'm getting that query is null. I bet that I am missing something basic, but what is it? Thank you.

EDIT:

Something is an interface that has several implementations, I'm choosing the implementation in the xml file `file.xml`. When I'm doing so using `context.getBean()`, it works and I have the right implementation, but when using `@Reousrce` (`javax.annotation.Resource`) I'm getting null.

What is the difference in flow when using context.getBean() and @Resource? Is there something different to how and when the values are initialized that might cause this?

EDIT #2: My list of dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.175</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: We could help if you provided a small but complete reproducible example. Failing that, what is `Something`? Where is it declared as a `bean`? `@Resource` is `javax.annotation.Resource`?

Comment: `Something` is an interface that has several implementations, I'm choosing the implementation in the xml file `file.xml`. When I'm doing so using `context.getBean()`, it works and I have the right implementation, but when using `@Reousrce` (`javax.annotation.Resource`) I'm getting null. Please let me know what else I can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Is `@Resource` on the classpath?

Comment: Does your running application's classpath contain the `javax.annotation.Resource` type?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. I'm importing `javax.annotation.Resource` otherwise I would not be able to use @Resrouce annotation... Also the class used, `Something` is defined as well - everything is working fine when using the `context.getBean`

Comment: You aren't using dependency injection. You are constructing a new instance of the application context and expect that to automagically inject beans into the instance that is creating the application context. That isn't going to work. Why are you creating, a new(?), instance of the context in your `BigDataOperation`?

Comment: I have to create it somewhere, right? I mean the code to load the context from the xml file needs to be written somewhere. This context is only important to `BigDataParent` and its children, so until someone uses them, nobody needs it. I take it from your question that I'm doing something wrong and there's a better approach. Please elaborate :)

Comment: Spring has extensive logging. Why did you not enable it and read any problems in there. Saves us from guessing.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Spring registers a number of [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) beans to perform bean injection. One of these is [`CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) which handles `@Resource` annotated members.

This `BeanPostProcessor` is only registered if `javax.annotation.Resource` is on the classpath when the program runs.

You must be running the application without providing it to the classpath.

---

Note that you must be providing it at compilation time, otherwise any references to it would fail. This is not the same as providing it at run time.

Comment: @apines Give an example of what? Do you know what a classpath is? How are you running your application?

Comment: I still do not understand the difference between `context.getBean()` to using `@Resource`, something basic is missing from my understanding. I know what a classpath is, but still do not understand what do you means when you say that Resource is on the classpath. If `@Resource` was not on the classpath, I would have gotten a compilation error.

Comment: @apines Two things. First: `context.getBean()` gets the bean directly from the context. `@Resource`, on the other hand, is processed by a `BeanPostProcessor` (read the various javadoc links). That `BeanPostProcessor` is only registered if the `javax.annotation.Resource` class is found on the classpath at run time. In your case it isn't, so no such `BeanPostProcessor` is registered and therefore the `@Resource` field remains unprocessed. As I said in my answer, it seems you are providing the class at compilation time, but not at run time.

Comment: How do I provide it properly then?

Comment: @apines When you run your `java` process, you can use the `-cp` option to set classpath entries.

Comment: @apines How are you launching/running your application?

Comment: I'm running it via InteliJ, and all the xml files are located in the resources folder, so the only thing that is missing is specifying the file like I'm doing with `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file.xml")`. If all I need is the file with the definition in the classpath, it should be there but it still not picking it up.

Comment: @apines Have you added all the appropriate `jars`? Are you using maven?

Comment: I'm using maven, I have the @Resource annotation - I can import it, everything compiles and runs, just returns null. Is there a specific extra spring dependency that I need to import? I'm importing `spring-context`

Comment: @apines Show us your dependencies. Edit them into your question. Is the dependency that provides `javax.annotation.Resource` set as `<scope>` of `provided`?

Comment: Edited the dependency list, not sure about the second question - I didn't need (or at least I don't think I needed) to import something specific to use the `@Resource` annotation.

Comment: @apines Look into how maven and Intellij interact. The `javax.annotation.Resource` should be provided by the JDK since Java 7. As a test, do `Class.forName("javax.annotation.Resource")`. What does that return?

Comment: I'm using jdk 7, and again I don't get compilation errors when using the annotation...

Comment: @apines There are two steps to a Java application. The compilation step, ie. `javac` with its own `-cp` option, and the launching step, ie. the `java` with its own `-cp` option. Classes that were present at compilation time might not be present at run time. You'll have to check how Intellij handles all that. I don't have experience with it.

Comment: Even when the class is in the jdk??

Comment: @apines That's what's surprising, but I can't see any other reason for the issue you're facing as you've described it.

Comment: Is there anything else that should be defined beside: 1. Make sure the xml files are either in main/resources or test/resources 2. Annotate the class we want to inject with `@Resource` 3. Let the magic happen?

Comment: @apines Nope, your configuration seems fine. Does your injection work with `@Autowired` and with `@Qualifier`?

Comment: @apines Then there is something else wrong. Post your full configuration file `file.xml` being loaded.